# Are all functions $f:\mathbf{Z}\to\mathbf{Z}$ "continuous"?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I read the following definitions in Glen E. Bredon's "Topology and Geometry":

> Let $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbf{R}^n$ and
>
> $$
> \text{dist}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i-y_i\right)^2\right)^{1/2}.
> $$
>
> Moreover, let $f:\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}^k$ be continuous at
>   $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbf{R}^n$ if
>
> $$
> \forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0\ni\text{dist}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right)<\delta\implies\text{dist}\left(f\left(\mathbf{x}\right),f\left(\mathbf{y}\right)\right)<\epsilon.
> $$

Using these definitions, can I prove that all functions $f:\mathbf{Z}\to\mathbf{Z}$ are "continuous" by setting $\delta=1$? I.e., $\text{dist}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\right)<1$ implies that $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}$ and therefore $\text{dist}\left(f\left(\mathbf{x}\right),f\left(\mathbf{y}\right)\right)=0<\epsilon$. Am I correct?

Although this fact may be useless, I am trying to ensure that my understanding of these concepts is sound.

Comment: You can prove this, and it is not useless.

Comment: Your idea is totally fine!

Comment: $f:\mathbb Z\to\text{anything}$ is continuous since the topology on $\mathbb Z$ is discrete.

Comment: Under the standard metric, yes. There are other interesting metrics on $\mathbb Z$ - the $p$-adic metrics -  for which not all functions are continuous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. In fact, all functions $\mathbb Z \rightarrow S$ are continuous for all topological spaces $S$ (or metric spaces, if your prefer). As you note, $\mathbb Z$ has the property that every singleton $\{x\}$ is an open set (i.e. the ball of radius $1$ about $x$ is $\{x\}$) More generally, you'd say that a topology in which all singletons are open is *discrete*. Any function with a discrete domain is continuous, because there's nothing to link elements to one another - that is, in $\mathbb R$, you have that if an open set contains $0$, it also contains some interval about $0$ - so $\{0\}$ is not an open set alone and any open set would contain some of the values near it.